# Change/prevent WCF redirection

Tags: c#, wcf

Running an old (we hope to phase it out soon(tm)) WCF Rest API. We got an endpoint like `GET .../MyService.svc/`. When WCF receives a request to  `GET .../MyService.svc` (without slash) it will automatically redirect to the resource with a slash (through an HTTP 307).

Is there any way to change this behavior to either throw an error, or, ideally, having the resource listen to either of those endpoints (generically)? Because obviously WCF finds the right resource (otherwise it couldn't redirect), so it would make much more sense to directly execute that call instead of redirecting - especially with a temporary 307.

Cheers!